# How to specify exceptions for method_opt when gathering statistics

Tags: oracle11g

Our database is set to gather schema statistics with something like

```
method_opt => 'for all columns size auto'
```

The problem is that this way histograms are assigned also for columns that better should not have histograms generated. Is there a way to set an exception for these columns (while leaving the auto-size for the other columns)?

Rationale: Some of our (indexed) columns are VARCHAR2(100) while the first 50 characters are almost identical - there are less than 10 different values among the first 50 characters. When column stats are being gathered, histograms are generated. But the histogram generation analyzes only the first 30 characters of the VARCHAR2 column, which leads to totally wrong histograms. (In fact, the values are almost uniformly distributed.)

**Edit:** My idea is to use something like 'for all columns size auto, but for columns(ECID) size 1'. But I don't know whether this is possible, the method_opt syntax is not very clear to me.

Comment: method_opt=>'for all columns size auto for columns size 1 ECID' does exactly what I need, but it works only for gather_table_stats, not for gather_schema_stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitive solution is to use

```
exec dbms_stats.set_table_prefs('schema','table','METHOD_OPT',''for all columns size auto for columns size 1 ECID');
```

and then gather the statistics normally using gather_schema_stats. This way I can get around the restrictions of method_opt for gather_schema_stats mentioned above. The current preferences can be viewed via

```
select * from dba_tab_stat_prefs;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the skewonly option that will only generate histograms on skewed data:

```
method_opt => 'for all columns size skewonly'
```

Comment: I think that this won't help, because even in case the statistics generator shall decide only according to the first 30 characters of the column, and shall thus decide that the column is skewed and needs histograms.

Answer (score 0):

What about `REPEAT`? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_stats.htm#i1036456 As in *REPEAT : Collects histograms only on the columns that already have histograms*